# JS Synchronous loop not stopping

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I have a button within a document that runs a function, The function is supposed to help users navigate between each user added on roblox. For some reason, my promise doesn't wait till the button is clicked again but goes through each element in the array within a few seconds. My code isn't a lot as I just encountered this error

**HTML**

```
       <div class="buttons">
           <div class="pass" onclick="manager('pass')">
               <img src="../assets/x.png">
           </div>
           <div class="check" onclick="manager('unfriend')">
               <img src="../assets/check.png">
           </div>
       </div>
```

**Function**

```
async function manager(type) {
    let friends = await getUsers();

   for(const user of friends) {
       let friend = await getUser(user.id)

     await (new Promise(((resolve => {
         if(type == 'pass') {
             username.innerText = friend.name;
             profile.src = friend.thumbnail
             return resolve()
         }
         
     }))))

   }
}
```

Comment: I see nothing that would make it wait for a click. I also don't see type defined anywhere.

Comment: It makes little sense to make something asynchronous that is not actually asynchronous .. the entire inner promise can/should be removed. It's also very convoluted for promises to make side-effect changes instead of returning values.

Comment: Makes no sense to loop if you need user interaction....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(type == 'pass')` is a simple test for the value of `type` at the point where that code is evaluated.

There is nothing there which would cause it to wait for the value of `type` to change.

(Certainly a Promise won't make code wait for anything: Your Promise *immediately* tests the value of `type` and then either sits pending for all time or immediately assigns `innerText` and `src` and then immediately resolves. Promises are tools to manage code which is already asynchronous, they can't make synchronous code asynchronous)

If you want to wait for a click on a button, then you need to have a click event listener.

Comment: Extension: If type != 'pass' when the promise is executed, then the promise is _never resolved_ and the `await` on the promise will _block indefinitely_.

Comment: Wouldn't the onclick property in html also count as a click event? I'm running the function in the end

Comment: @fxncis — If you are calling `manager` in response to a click event then that's fine, but it isn't going to have any effect on a promise in the middle of that function.

Comment: @Quentin, I'll try using a click event. I'll come back if I have any issues.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about a click event. The main reason I think this is because I have an array with data of roblox users and once you click the pass div it'll show another person in the array. Meaning, I'd have to get the current user and move on to the next. Unlike the function as I would have it move onto the next user in the for loop.

Comment: If you want to stop and then not do anything "till the button is clicked again" then you'll need a click event to know when the button is clicked again (and since you want to iterate to the next item when the click event happens, you shouldn't be using a for loop).

Comment: If that so, how would I get the current user and then move onto the next without a loop?

Comment: You'll need to count in a variable outside the function

Comment: So basically, when the default user is "posted" I'll have a variable with the number of the position in the element of that specific user and whenever the skip or check is clicked it'll get the position in the array then go to the next one.